# I can't copy to a folder on the Network with php On Windows

Tags: php, networking, permissions, permission-denied

> mkdir(): Permission denied in

```
<?php
$old= 'index.php';
$new= 'Z:\index.php';// Or \\192.168.1.1\File\Filename.php

if (!copy($old, $new)) {
    echo "$old can not copied ...\n";
}

?>
```

[image: image1]

> mkdir(): Permission denied in

I can't access a folder on the network with php.
Access or create folder or copy folder.

I will create a directory and ı will write a file this directory and finish.
But I have errors.I try to copy it's same for this.

With this code, it is possible to open a folder in the computer, but it is not possible to access a folder on the network. This is my problem.

It can not work.
[image: image2]

Comment: And which role is for Oracle here?

Comment: You need to make sure the account which PHP runs under has permission to write to that folder. (It's generally not the same account that you run as when using the computer yourself.

Comment: @ADyson How i can control this ? This Network Permissions Everyone have Read Write and all of this but php can't create a file.But if i am in the network and i can use cmd.exe and write mkdir x this is running. He create "x" folder in network but php can not do this why i can't understand this.

Comment: Are you sure the PHP user account even has the drive mapped? Try using the UNC path instead

Comment: @ADyson can you control again ? I tried this but it can't do